# File listing on tab completion

Tags: bash, python, autocomplete

I experienced a strange behavior of bash shell `tab completion` while trying to run a python code.

When I use more than one character followed by `-` prefixed argument, I am able to select the a file using tab completion, but with just one character it completely fails. Here are some examples:

```
#failed 
python prepare_yaml_files.py -i in<tab><tab>

#succeed: though `-in` is not valid 
python prepare_yaml_files.py -in in<tab><tab>

#succeed: valid argument 
python prepare_yaml_files.py --in in<tab><tab>
```

I wonder why this happens. Do I need to set some preference in `.bashrc` to address this.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're suffering from a bad autocompletion script.
I took a look at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/python` on Debian, and as far as I can tell, it only autocompletes filenames ending in `.py`, `.py` or `.pyo` if the previous word is (some variant of) `python`, or a single-character option.

I'm going to assume that the assumption here is that everything that looks like `-X` is an argument to the interpreter, would be given before the command to run, and you'd still need to give the name of a script. So only files matching `.py` and `.py[oc]` are presented.

You can completely disable the programmable autocompletion with `shopt -u progcomp`. A finer fix would require editing the autocompletion script(s).

The rule I'm looking at is this, I'm not sure if I interpreted it completely:

```
    case $prev in
        [...]
        !(?(*/)python*([0-9.])|-?))
            [[ $cword -lt 2 || ${words[cword-2]} != -@(Q|W) ]] \
                && _filedir
            ;;
```